# Gridview rows validation based on two columns using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a gridview with many columns.  When I click submit button I want to loop through its rows and perform a client side validation check.  The first column to check has a dropdown list, and the second has a textbox.

If a value is selected in the dropdown list the textbox in the second column should not be empty.

How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: You need to make an attempt at the solution youself. Then, if you run into a specific problem with your code, ask for advice

Comment: The below code helps me to check if the user has selected a value from the dropdown for atleast one row in the grid.  But I also want to make sure that another textbox in the same row should not be blank if the user has selected a value in the dropdown.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
               
               $('select.ddlMyClass').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() != "-Select-") {
                        $("#hdnSelected").val("True");
                    }
                });
               
                if ($("#hdnSelected").val() == "False") {
                    alert("Please select a value from the dropdown.");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });